# CKEditor 5 React custom image upload adapter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor5

I am trying to implement custom upload adapter but it is not working.
On uploading image my upload function is not running(upload function is created inside uploadAdapter function) and no request is getting sent to backend. Please see what is the problem in code.

const API_URl = "https://noteyard-backend.herokuapp.com";
const UPLOAD_ENDPOINT = "api/blogs/uploadImg";

```
function uploadAdapter(loader) {
    return {
        upload: () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const body = new FormData();
                loader.file.then(file => {
                    body.append("uploadImg", file);
```

//AuthorizedApi is simple axios request.

```
                    AuthorizedApi.post(`${API_URl}/${UPLOAD_ENDPOINT}`, {
                        body,
                    })
                        
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(res => {
                            resolve({ default: `${API_URl}/${res.url}` });
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            reject(err);
                        });
                });
            });
        },
    };
}

function uploadPlugin(editor) {
    editor.plugins._plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = loader => {
        return uploadAdapter(loader);
    };
        }
```

```
//This is my CKEditor code snippet
<CKEditor
                        editor={TextEditor}
                        config={{
                            ...EDITOR_CONFIG[theme],
                            extraPlugins: [uploadPlugin],
                            link: {
                                defaultProtocol: "https://",
                            },
                        }}
                        data={stripTrackingImage(value) ?? ""}
                        onReady={editor => {
                            //add toolbar
                            window.editor = editor;
                            if (disabled) {
                                editor.isReadOnly = true;
                            } else {
                                document
                                    .querySelector(`#${toolbarId}`)
                                    ?.appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
                                editor.on("handle_attachment_click", addAttachment);
                                //adjust tooltip position
                                editor.ui.view.toolbar.items.map(item => {
                                    //button positionging( without dropdowns)
                                    item.tooltipPosition = "se";
                                    //for dropdowns
                                    if (item.buttonView) {
                                        item.buttonView.tooltipPosition = "se";
                                    }
                                    return item;
                                });
                            }
                            console.log(editor, "editor");
                        }}
                        onChange={(event, editor) => setValue(editor.getData())}
                        isReadOnly={disabled}
                    />
```

```
On uploading image , no request is getting sent to given URL, please try to find the problem
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.